# smooth structure on complete intersection

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

A complete intersection is an algebraic variety cut out by homogenous polynomials. Geometrically, this is the intersection of hypersurfaces in complex projective space.

Below, let's confine to the non-singluar case. These are smooth manifolds and much topological information could be read out from the degrees of the polynomials used. see 
**wikipedia**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_intersection#Topology

and **manifold atlas**

http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Complete_intersections

for a survey.

I am interested in the `smooth structures on the homeomorphism types of complete intersection`.

In particular, **are there two complete intersections which are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic**?  In the paper

*An example of two homeomorphic, nondiffeomorphic complete intersection surfaces. 
Invent. Math. 99 (1990), no. 3, 651–654.*

Wolfgang Ebeling gave an example in the surface case. **How about higher dimensions**?

Comment: "A complete intersection is an algebraic variety cut out by homogenous polynomials" - A complete intersection in projective space is a variety cut out by a number of homogeneous equations equal to its codimension.

Comment: The Manifold Atlas page you link to contains information on the (topological) Sullivan conjecture, which says that complete intersections are (homeomorphic) diffeomorphic iff they have the same multi-degree, Pontryagin classes and Euler number. Crowley and Nagy announced a proof of the Sullivan conjecture in complex dimension 4 (https://www.newton.ac.uk/seminar/20181206160016301) but I don't know if the details are written up yet.